# 404 page not showing

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a 404 page on a static site on my localhost(MAMP) setup. The file is called 404.html (at the root of the site) and in my .htacccess file (at the root of the site) I have placed the following line of code:

`ErrorDocument 404  /404.html`

However the 404.html page doesn't show when I type an incorrect URL. I've done a test to confirm the 404.html page does show though when doing mysite/404.html.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is the path to the 404.html correct? Please show the setup.

Comment: I've added an image of my file structure. The code from the .htaccess file has been cut and pasted into the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and for me it was a misconfigured `httpd.conf`, maybe that can fix it for you:
The file is located at `MAMP_Root\apache\conf\httpd.conf`.
In my file there was a `ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"` line and I just needed to comment it out to fix the problem.
Also can you please post your full `.htaccess` file, it could contain other stuff that interferes (I'd add this as a comment but I don't have enough rep, sorry).

Comment: Hi @Sv443, there's nothing else in the .htaccess file. I've just found out the problem though, I need to use the full path, hence the code that works is `ErrorDocument 404  /sitename/404.html`. I'll answer it when the time limit allows me to answer my own question. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.

Comment: Oh okay. You said the file was located in your ht-document-root, in that case it should've worked but that explains it.